# Buttons with similar properties

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 5 buttons that share the same class but have individual id's. Each button when clicked should translate the the text associated with the button. Unfortunately it is deferring to the first button. Here is my code for the click event. I also included the html. Thanks for the help!

```
$(".common").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var translateText = $(".common").text();
    if ($("#restroom").text() === "Restroom?") {
        translateText = "Where is the nearest bathroom?";
    } else if ($("#atm").text() === "ATM?") {
        translateText = "Where is the nearest bank or ATM?";
    } else if ($("#train").text() === "Train?") {
        translateText = "Where is the nearest train?";
    } else if ($("#coffee").text() === "Coffee?") {
        translateText = "Where can I get a good cup of coffee?";
    } else if ($("#restaurant").text() === "Restaurant?") {
        translateText = "What is the best restaurant in town?";
    } else if ($("#market").text() === "Market?") {
        translateText = "Where is the nearest market?";
    }; 

<div>
        <p>Commonly asked Questions:</p>
        <button type="button" id="restroom" class="btn btn-warning common">Restroom?</button>
        <button type="button" id="atm" class="btn btn-warning common atm">ATM?</button>
        <button type="button" id="train" class="btn btn-warning common">Train?</button>
        <button type="button" id="coffee" class="btn btn-warning common">Coffee?</button>
        <button type="button" id="restaurant" class="btn btn-warning common">Restaurant?</button>
        <button type="button" id="market" class="btn btn-warning common">Market?</button>
```

Comment: Each one of the buttons has a unique id that you could compare against, so you wouldn't have to drill down and grab the inner text.  Not sure why you didn't use that.  Edit: but yeah, as the answers show, you need to use the reference to the button clicked, not do lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text of the clicked button and change the text of the question correspondingly:

```js
$(".common").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let translateText = $(this).text();
    let question;
    if (translateText === "Restroom?") {
        question = "Where is the nearest bathroom?";
    } else if (translateText === "ATM?") {
        question = "Where is the nearest bank or ATM?";
    } else if (translateText === "Train?") {
        question = "Where is the nearest train?";
    } else if (translateText === "Coffee?") {
        question = "Where can I get a good cup of coffee?";
    } else if (translateText === "Restaurant?") {
        question = "What is the best restaurant in town?";
    } else if (translateText === "Market?") {
        question = "Where is the nearest market?";
    }
    if(translateText)
         $('#question').text(question);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <p>Commonly asked Questions:</p>
      <button type="button" id="restroom" class="btn btn-warning common">Restroom?</button>
      <button type="button" id="atm" class="btn btn-warning common atm">ATM?</button>
      <button type="button" id="train" class="btn btn-warning common">Train?</button>
      <button type="button" id="coffee" class="btn btn-warning common">Coffee?</button>
      <button type="button" id="restaurant" class="btn btn-warning common">Restaurant?</button>
      <button type="button" id="market" class="btn btn-warning common">Market?</button>
</div>
<p id="question"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Majed I appreciate the follow up! Unfortunately when I run this in my code it translates the word restroom in the target language. I may not have been as clear as I needed to be. I am passing the variable translateText to a function that takes  the "question" and uses google translate to a selected language. Does that change anything? I'm still learning and appreciate the feedback.

Comment: thanks again this worked with a few tweaks to my code. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do this and one that is easier to scale and maintain is to use an object to store the values using the term as keys and data attributes to store the terms on the buttons.

```js
const translations = {
  "restroom": "Where is the nearest bathroom?",
  "atm": "Where is the nearest bank or ATM?",
  "train": "Where is the nearest train?",
  "coffee": "Where can I get a good cup of coffee?"
}

$('.common').click(function(){
   // `this` is the element the event occurred on
   const term = $(this).data('term');
   const translateText = translations[term];
   // do something with the text
   console.log(translateText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Commonly asked Questions:</p>
<button type="button" data-term="restroom" class="btn btn-warning common">Restroom?</button>
<button type="button" data-term="atm" class="btn btn-warning common atm">ATM?</button>
<button type="button" data-term="train" class="btn btn-warning common">Train?</button>
<button type="button" data-term="coffee" class="btn btn-warning common">Coffee?</button>
```